# Search bar changes autolayout constraints of edges for extended layout

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

When starting my controller with search bar integrated in the navigation bar, and position all the views below it with setting `setEdgesForExtendedLayout` parameter to `UIRectEdgeNone` everything displays correctly.

Here search bar is at the top, integrated in navigation bar and all other views are below it.

Now, the weird part is that I have a button below in the view that pushes another controller (I have `definesPresentationContext` set to `YES`) it displays fine, but on back when `searchBar` did not get focus at all constraints are intact. As soon as I click on search bar and type something and then click the button to present another controller...on going back view goes under top bars.

I have in `viewWillAppear` setter for `setEdgesForExtendedLayout` and for `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent` set to `NO`, but for some reason this is not respected at all, and view goes under navigation bar.

Any idea what I have missed? Tried this on both iOS 11 and iOS 10 and it doesn't work, so this is not related to iOS 11 only.

Just to be more clear, here is the code I use for displaying all of this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Top view
    self.topView = [TLProfileHeaderView newAutoLayoutView];
    self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.topView];
    [self.topView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop];
    [self.topView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft];
    [self.topView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight];
    [self.topView autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:self.topView withMultiplier:0.53];

    UIButton *inviteFriendsButton = [UIButton newAutoLayoutView];
    [inviteFriendsButton setTitle:@"INVITE FRIENDS TO USE MY APP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [inviteFriendsButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [inviteFriendsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(presentNextController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:inviteFriendsButton];

    [inviteFriendsButton autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.topView];
    [inviteFriendsButton autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft];
    [inviteFriendsButton autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight];
    [inviteFriendsButton autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:[TLDimensionHelper gpsCellHeight]*0.8];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Enter name or email";
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}

- (void)presentNextController:(UIButton *)sender {
    MyNextVC *nextVC = [MyNextVC new];
    [self presentViewController:nextVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you found solution for this, because it also happens to me?

Comment: Had to go with another solution to avoid this issue. Made my own search controller with labels, buttons and textView inserted in uiview. Works like a charm now.